# Single template will not show sidebar/bottom-nav and footer

Tags: templates, sidebar, single

Im using the blankslate template theme and have a sidebar which i would like to use throughout the website.

On my sidebar on the homepage i have a widget called latest posts with the latest post snippet and a read-more link. When this is clicked, the user should be able to view the single post on a new page with the header, footer, bottom/top nav and sidebar. At the moment the sidebar/footer and bottom nav are missing.

I have deactivated the widget and used Wordpress original and this still does not work (so i know its not a sidebar widget bug). If i move the footer or sidebar tags up in the template say next to the header they show but the post is below so i know its something to do with the single post function?

Here is my index template below:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'nav', 'above' ); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'nav', 'below' ); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Which i want the single page template to be like but instead of all the posts the single post... The single post template i have so far is:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'nav', 'above-single' ); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'nav', 'below-single' ); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have moved everything about and still no luck. If anyone could give me any guidance i'd appriciate it. Thanks.

Update: I've just realised my tool bar goes when i also access this page - not sure if this will help towards my query.

Comment: I believe get_sidebar() should be outside the loop - meaning move it after the endwhile;. Have you tried that?

Comment: I'd guess there is an error in your `single.php` file. Please add [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to the question.

Comment: I've tried added it both in and out the loop, when the loop is removed from the single.php everything works so I assume its something to do with that. I will post any errors I may have when I get back to my laptop. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking each template include, the single footer contained an error. To resolve this, i duplicated the code from the index footer and amended for the single template. Thank you for your replies.